# Chromecast: How to send a JSON object from the Android device to the Chromecast Receiver App?

Tags: android, json, chromecast

I read the [sendMessage() of ChromeCast APIs on Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/Cast.CastApi.html#sendMessage), and didn't found any clues of sending a JSON Obj. it seems that only support String.

But i read the Chromecast Receiver APIs, which said the receiving of JSON Obj is possible.

or should i just stringlize the JSON obj and use the sendMessage() method on Android?

is there probably an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send any "String" as the message payload. If you want to send a JSON object, you need to serialize that to string and send that over. On the receiver side, you can decide to retrieve that as a string or as a JSON object. And yes, sendMessage() is the way to go for custom message but a number of control commands (like load, play, ..) can accept a JSON object as a custom data to be sent to the receiver if that is all you need and the timing is right.

Comment: thanks, may i ask one more question, the receiver may receive different datas for different purposes, e.g. "user info", "game data" and so on... so is it better to send the data through different `channels` for different purposes which would be implemented in Android app? Since i'm still new to chromecast development, so i don't really know the best approach to deal with the channel thing :)

Comment: I would suggest using one custom namespace for all these messages and in the message itself have a field to specify the type of message, whether it is userinfo, gamedata, etc.